# Returning results for a sqlite query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following query in sqlite:

```
select * from Questions 
where Subject = ? and Grade = ? and Level = ? and Used = ? 
ORDER BY RANDOM() 
LIMIT 1
```

```java
PreparedStatement pst = gui.connectionQuestions.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1,gui.textSubjectQTest);
pst.setString(2,gui.showGradeLabel.getText());
pst.setString(3,gui.showCurrentLevelLabel.getText());
pst.setString(4,"1");
```

Where the 4th value stand for the column `used`. This column takes 3 values, how can I returned the results for all possible values of `used` field?

**EDIT:** When I erase the field edit from the DB browser for sqlite everything works fine, however when I do so from my Java code I got the following message:

**EDIT2:** I remove also the //pst.setString(4,"1"); and now seems to work fine.

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3

Comment: So you want the same effect as if the query did not have the `used=?` filter?

Comment: If you want all values of `Used` simply remove `Used = ?`

Comment: Yeah you are right. I tried to perform the query in teh DB browser for SQLITE and for some reason when I perform the query I take all the time one result (if I re-run the query I got another result) seems really weird but I think it is a software issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all values of `Used` simply remove that section of your `where`:

```
select * from Questions 
where Subject = ? and Grade = ? and Level = ?
ORDER BY RANDOM() 
LIMIT 1
```

After remove the last line of Java which is attempting to put something into it:

```
PreparedStatement pst = gui.connectionQuestions.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1,gui.textSubjectQTest);
pst.setString(2,gui.showGradeLabel.getText());
pst.setString(3,gui.showCurrentLevelLabel.getText());
```